# I can't change the fontsize, is something overiding my commands?

Tags: fonts, fontsize

I can't seem to change the fontsize at all. It seems as though there is overiding code in my document but I don't know where. Here is my preamble code with title page etc.:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
%\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[notlof,notlot]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
%\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{adjustbox}



\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{14}{12}\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\paragraph}{%
  \@startsection{paragraph}{4}%
  {\z@}{1.2ex \@plus 1ex \@minus .2ex}{-1em}%
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}%
}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\makeatother
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}


\begin{document}
\sloppy
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}

% Upper part of the page. The '~' is needed because \\
% only works if a paragraph has started.


\textsc{\Large text}\\[1.5cm]

% Title

\vspace{2cm}

{ \LARGE \bfseries text \\[0.4cm] }

\vspace{2cm}

{ \Large \bfseries name \\[0.4cm] }

\vspace{1cm}

\textsc{\Large text}\\[0.5cm]
\textsc{\Large text}\\[0.5cm]

\vspace{3cm}

\textsc{\normalsize text}\\[0.5cm]
\textsc{\normalsize text}\\[0.5cm]
\textsc{\normalsize text}\\[0.5cm]

\newpage\

\thispagestyle{empty}\textsc{\large text}\\[0.5cm]

\vspace{15cm} 

\textsc{\large text}\\[0.5cm]
\textsc{\large text}\\[0.5cm]

\end{center}
\end{titlepage}


\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage
\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage

\pagenumbering{roman}
\abstract

\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage

{\newgeometry{left=0.98in,right=0.98in,top=0.98in,bottom=1.5in}
%\addtocontents{toc}{~\hfill\textbf{Page}\par}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\tableofcontents\thispagestyle{empty}\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{2ex}\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{0.5ex}



\listoffigures\thispagestyle{empty}\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{2ex}\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{0.5ex}

\listoftables\thispagestyle{empty}\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{2ex}\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{0.5ex}

\setcounter{page}{1}
%\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}
\pagestyle{fancy}\fancyhead[R]{Introduction}\fancyhead[L]{Chapter 1}

\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage



\chapter{Introduction}
```

Thanks,
Michael

*Note to administrators...I am both logged in and logged out of my account so I can only post as a guest. It is either a problem with my browser or my account (although I'm not sure merging my accounts will work). I go to log in and before I type in my details it tells me I have logged in but I haven't...so I apologise for replying with answers, I have no choice...

Comment: You should try to build a **Minimal** (Possibly Non-)Working Example: load one package at time, use the simplest body which can raise the "error", and then repost. Usually you will find the problem (and often the solution as well) in making the MWE.

Answer (score 5):

`\fontsize{14}{12}`takes effect after `\selectfont` so in your case should take effect after the `\bfseries` (if it doesn't supply an example document that shows the problem)

but don't do this: this is specifying a 14pt font on a 12pt baseline so will make wildly inconsistent vertical spacing depending on the heights of the letters used.

You should vary rarely need to use `\fontsize` other than setting up the named sizes such as `\large`.